# coffee doesn't work in heroku

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

My bootstrap dropdown menu and `user.coffee` works in production mode on my computer, but in heroku it doesn't work.

I have precompiled 1000 time, I need help please.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

config.assets.compile = true
  config.serve_static_assets = tru

This is my repository:
https://github.com/angeluzmx/app3